# When executing Python script on Linux; cannot see text written when prompt returns and no newline characters when pressing enter

Tags: python, linux

Whenever I execute a Python script I made, which uses subprocesses, I noticed that whenever execution is finished and the prompt is returned - I can no longer see text written after the prompt. For example, I write 'ls' and can only see

```
root@kali#
```

When I press enter a few times, I get:

```
root@kali# root@kali# root@kali# root@kali# root@kali# root@kali#
```

The only thing that I can think of is that there's something wrong with using `subprocess.call` with `shell=true`.

No Python traceback errors appear and the program seems to execute perfectly fine. However, its rather annoying having to CTRL+T and use a new terminal after each execution.

Comment: Please look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're dealing with a faulty program that changed some terminal settings, and failed to reset them - I can't tell if it's your program, or one you're invoking with `subprocess.call()`.  Try blindly typing the `reset` command to get the terminal back in a good state.

Comment: I realised that I am sending standard output to /dev/null and backgrounding processes. So my terminal isn't returning, since there is still stuff running in the background, I can't cleanly type commands. Thank you for the tip about reset

Comment: This isn't a general problem with subprocesses, it's something specific to the program that you're running in the subprocess. What are you running?